# Are the models of the vive-controls embedded for offline use?

Tags: aframe, htc-vive

The model of the vive wand is an obj with an mtl.
Where does a-frame get this model from?
Is it loaded via internet or is the model included within the framework?

I have to know if my PC needs an internet connection to play a game with vive controls.

Answer (score 1):

It's loaded over the Internet. The models are hosted at https://github.com/aframevr/assets/tree/gh-pages/controllers ... accessible via `https://cdn.aframe.io/<PATH_TO_FILE>`.

If you check the component file, you can see the URL: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/vive-controls.js

```
var VIVE_CONTROLLER_MODEL_OBJ_URL = 'https://cdn.aframe.io/controllers/vive/vr_controller_vive.obj';
var VIVE_CONTROLLER_MODEL_OBJ_MTL = 'https://cdn.aframe.io/controllers/vive/vr_controller_vive.mtl';
```

The documentation mentions it as well https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/vive-controls.html#assets

Doesn't seem like an easy way to load locally, besides forking the component. You could also try methods like Service Workers to cache those assets offline.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! I've downloaded the two files and changed the path to the local files. Now I can use the game offline.